# Priorise a Luigi workflow compare to anther workflow

Tags: python, task, workflow, scheduler, luigi

I have two Luigi workflows, `wfA` and `wfB`. I set priority for each task of both Luigi workflow and all `wfA` task have a higher priority of `wfB` task.
If I run both workflow simultaneously with a `--workers=1`, each workflow will have one active task.
If I choose `--workers=3` each workflow will have three active tasks but both workflows still independent, the priority field effect is limit to one workflow.

What I like to do is to add a global workers value (for all workflow) and to schedule tasks with highest priority (looking in all workflow).
So, in my example, if I set a global workers limit to `3` then run both workflow `wfA` and `wfB`, I want all task of `wfA` to be schedule (by group of 3 max) **then** all `taks` of `wfB` to be schedule because tasks of `wfA` have an higher priority compared to `wfB` tasks

Here is an example of wfA and wfB.

`wfA`:

```
import time
import luigi


class TaskA1(luigi.Task):
    priority = 110

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output1.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


class TaskA2(luigi.Task):
    priority = 111

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output2.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


class TaskA3(luigi.Task):
    priority = 112

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output3.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


class TaskA4(luigi.Task):
    priority = 113

    def requires(self):
        return [TaskA1(), TaskA2(), TaskA3()]

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output4.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.build([TaskA4()], workers=3)
```

`wfB`:

```
import time
import luigi


class TaskB1(luigi.Task):
    priority = 10

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output1.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


class TaskB2(luigi.Task):
    priority = 11

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output2.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


class TaskB3(luigi.Task):
    priority = 12

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output3.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


class TaskB4(luigi.Task):
    priority = 13

    def requires(self):
        return [TaskA1(), TaskA2(), TaskA3()]

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output4.txt")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write("This is some dummy data")
        time.sleep(8)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.build([TaskB4()], workers=3)
```

I want to execute both works simentaniously and the scheduler to schedule `wfA` tasks **then** `wfB` tasks.